# Applying the text from the image height and width

Tags: javascript

I have code like this

```
<script src='js.js'></script>
    <script>
    (function($){
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName('x'),
          L = img.width(),
          T = img.height();
    for (var i=0,len=img.length;i<len;i++){
    img[i] = $('#u').text("Width" + L + "Height " + T)
    }
    });
    </script>
<div id='image'>
    <img class='x' src='1.jpg'/>
    <span id='u'></span>
    </div>
    <div id='image'>
    <img class='x' src='5.jpg'/>
    <span id='u'></span>
    </div>
```

i want to applying text width and height of image in `<span id='u'></span>`
but does not work,

Comment: the image doesnt get fully loaded on document.ready.. use image's on load to set the text

Comment: Multiple elements with the same id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to get fully loaded..

So HTML is

```
    <div id='image'>
        <img class='x' src='1.jpg'/>
        <span id='u'></span> </div> <div id='image'>
        <img class='x' src='5.jpg'/>
        <span id='u'></span> 
</div>
```

Apply the code as

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
                    // reset src back to original..so that it works on cached images
                     $('img').each(function()
                     {
                  $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src")+"?_="+Math.random());
             });

                   $('img').load(function()
                     {
                           var h =  $(this).height();
                           var w =  $(this).width();
                           // nearest span ..set its text
                    $(this).parent().find('span').html("Height :"+h +"_ _ _"+"Width :"+w); 
                      }
                  ); //end img load   

    });

</script>
```

**Edit** : If image get cached image load event doesn't fire correctly,
 added code to reset the src

Added : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rUctn/15/)

http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/08/05/jquery-check-whether-image-is-loaded/

Comment: do you mean the answer? or the question?

Comment: the syntax used in the question is not correct. i edited my answer.

Comment: but why not turn up the width and height of the text on <span id='u'></span> .....??

Comment: ah `image caching` .. the browser caches images hence image load event doesnt fire.. added an edit to code.. should work now.

Comment: yw @Zhinto .. please mark this as answer if it is working for you :) thx